# neo4j cypher filter nodes apoc dijkstra

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a graph, and i want to use the apoc dijkstra algorithm on it, so far everything is working. But i want to exclude certain nodes or node properties from the possible path, so that the dijkstra algorithm doesnt return a path that contains these excluded nodes or properties.

Is it possible, for example, to filter all existing nodes BEFORE calling the apoc.dijkstra algorithm?

I know that is it possible to filter the found path AFTER the algorithm, but then it is possible that there is a possible path in the graph that was not found, because the filterting of the nodes occurred afterwards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apoc dijkstra is an old an deprecated implementation of Dijkstra algorithm. You should check out the Graph Data Science plugin at https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/. It supports shortest weighted path algorithm or otherwise known as dijkstra algorithm, https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/shortest-path/. You can can define which nodes you want and relationships you want to traverse when projecting the graph.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot, this sounds very much for what i am looking for

Comment: This helped a lot in understand how the projection in the algorithms work: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/native-projection/

Comment: also this: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/cypher-projection/